# Rails 5 and ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to learn a bit about ActiveModelSerializers in Rails 5. I was following this [tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/building-a-json-api-with-rails-5/) and ran into some bugs:

I probably shouldn't be messing around with Rails 5 beta right?

```
rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.beta3
```

and Ruby:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160303205439) do

  create_table "rental_units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "rooms"
    t.integer  "bathrooms"
    t.integer  "price_cents"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "rental_units", ["user_id"], name: "index_rental_units_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "email"
  end

end
```

Here is my seeds:

```
User.create(name: "1st user", email: "1stemail@gmail.com")
User.create(name: "2nd user", email: "2ndemail@gmail.com")
User.create(name: "3rd user", email: "3rdemail@gmail.com")

RentalUnit.create(address: "1st address", rooms: 2, bathrooms: 2, price_cents: 50000, user_id:1)
RentalUnit.create(address: "2nd address", rooms: 2, bathrooms: 2, price_cents: 50000, user_id:1)
RentalUnit.create(address: "3rd address", rooms: 2, bathrooms: 2, price_cents: 50000, user_id:1)
RentalUnit.create(address: "4th address", rooms: 2, bathrooms: 2, price_cents: 50000, user_id:2)
```

Here is my RentalUnit Model:

```
class RentalUnit < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here is my RentalUnitSerializer:

```
class RentalUnitSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :address, :rooms, :bathrooms, :price, :price_per_room
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try to run rails server, I get:

```
rs
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.beta3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Jwan/Dropbox/programming/rails/api_codeship/app/serializers/rental_unit_serializer.rb:3:in `<class:RentalUnitSerializer>': undefined method `belongs_to' for RentalUnitSerializer:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Jwan/Dropbox/programming/rails/api_codeship/app/serializers/rental_unit_serializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Any idea what is going on?

Anyone have any good tutorials on API design, Rails APIs, and AMS that are working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `has_one` or `has_many` relationship in your `RentalUnit` model (and maybe `User` model too). Add `belongs_to :user` in your `RentalUnit` model and either `has_one` or `has_many` in your `User` model depending on what you want.

I'm using Rails 5beta2 and ActiveModel Serializer and it's working fine... guessing beta3 should be only be better.

Comment: I see so the belongs_to in the RentalUnitSerializer is insufficient?

Comment: Correct because the Serializer takes the Model and converts it to JSON. If the model has no `user_id` field, then there is no data to say which user it belongs to.

Comment: So then what does the belongs_to :user do in the Serializer anyway?

Comment: Compare the JSON response with and without the `belongs_to`.